# Pass variable into command line in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, spyder

I'm trying to make a function to automate my commits in Spyder, as  find myself typing the following a lot:

```
!git init
!git add myfilename.py
!git commit -m "my commit comment"
```

But to work as a function I need to be able to pass the file names I enter for the function arguments I get an unsurprising error: "fatal: pathspec 'file' did not match any files"

```
def gitCommit(*files, commit = "Place Commit Comment Here"):
    !git init
    for file in files:
        !git add file
    !git commit -m paste(commit)
```

I'm not sure how to escape the "!" aspect of the code that clearly doesnt recognize the variable "file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and it should work:-

`!git add $file`

I have just checked the documentation.

[Ipython Magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

> Aliases expand Python variables just like system calls using `!` or `!!`
>   do: all expressions prefixed with `‘$’` get expanded. For details of the
>   semantic rules, see PEP-215:...

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.

Interestingly enough it works within quotes too, took my a while to get the comment to work as I would not have guess that.

comment = "Place Commit Comment Here" 
    !git commit -m "$comment"